# CSS corrupted and gone blanked - How can i recover it. - (PC BOSD & Restarted)

Tags: css

CSS corrupted and gone blanked - how can i recover it.

problem PC BOSD and Restarted when i BOSD i was editing and CSS file. soon after i restart the pc the CSS gone blanked. all browser cash also show blank as well.

Please give a solution.

Comment: This should be posted on http://superuser.com/ , not here.

Comment: thank you. i posted in there here is the link
[link]http://superuser.com/questions/529311/css-corrupted-and-gone-blanked-how-can-i-recover-it-pc-bosd-restarted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you lost your CSS file's contents in your editor, it's likely gone.

Unless you have backups, he only place where you *might* be able to fetch it from is a browser cache (maybe on some other machine that accessed the page) -  depending on cache settings, it may be gone there as well, but it's worth a try.